# how to link tables in birt report

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have 2 tables in my BIRT report.

First table represents the total usage for a customer in current month and the second table represents the total usage for the previous month.

I want the difference between the total usage of the above 2 tables.

Please let me know how can I do that using birt.

Thanks

Comment: Is all of your table data coming from a single data source?

Comment: no, all of my table data is from different data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to store totals of each table in persistent variables. For example click the data element containing the aggregation of the first table -> script tab -> onCreate

```
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("currentM", this.value);
```

And we can do the same with the second table:

```
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("previousM", this.value);
```

Finally we insert a new data element with an expression like:

```
var currentM=reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("currentM");
var previousM=reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("previousM");

currentM-previousM;
```

It is important to note this data element should be inserted after these two tables, so that global variables are populated before the expression is evaluated

Comment: Also. for future reference could you please let me know if there is any good documentation for writing scripts in BIRT ? Thank you once again :)

Comment: Could you please give me some pointers on how I can modify the same to work in such a way that if there are multiple records for different customers in the report tables. Then how I could take the difference of them?

Comment: If there are multiple records for different customers then could you please let me know how could I take the difference in this case ?